# relationships Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here's my question (I'm a beginner):
I have an app with two tables, user and report
a report belongs to a user
on each user page, I've successfully displayed their reports.
What I can't figure out how to do is display on the homepage

"name of the report" by "user who wrote that report"

Can anybody help please ?!

Answer (score 0):

if

```
User 
  has_may :reports

Report
  belongs_to :user
```

then u can find reports for any user by (irrespective of the page)

```
@user.reports #until u have the user object
```

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for more info.

to display the last report for each user, do

```
@users = User.includes(:reports)
```

in view

```
@users.each do |user|
  = user.name
  = user.report.last.name
```

Comment: This is what I get then:

NoMethodError in HomeController#index

    undefined method `reports' for nil:NilClass

Comment: and I do have the following:
User 
  has_many :reports

Report
  belongs_to :user

Comment: add before_filter :authenticate_user! to ur home controller if u r using devise. u will get the current_user object on which u can call reports as current_user.reports

Comment: yes, I am, I got started with RailsApps (https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan)

Comment: What I want to do is display the last reports and the name of the users who wrote them. So I need to call all reports (I manage to display a specific users' reports )

Comment: do @reports = Report.includes(:user) and then iterate over the reports  and display its related user as report.user.name

Comment: the includes method will save u from N+1 problem

Comment: I'm not sure that answers my questions

Comment: The reason why you are getting the error mentioned in the first comment is, `@users` is nil. Its not being fetched properly.

If you want to access users who wrote reports, you need `@report.user` where `@report` is an instance variable pointing to only one report.

I'm still not much clear with the problem, can you please update the schema of both reports and users table ?